# MIN DATE with Two Tables and multiple instances of same item

Tags: sql, date, join, min

I have two tables; `Items` and `Items_history` that I'm trying to join.

- First table (`Items`): Has one instance of item key with a current date
- Second table (`Items_history`): Has multiple instances of the same item key with multiple dates. Only want item key from first table to have min date of second table

```
Items Table:                   Items_History table:        Results:
item_key    date               item_key       date          item_key   date
1          1/1/2019              1          1/1/2019          1       8/30/2018
2          12/30/2018            1          10/30/2018        2       10/15/2018
                                 1          08/30/2018
                                 2          12/30/2018
                                 2          10/15/2018
```

What I have so far:

```
select c.item_key,min(a.CREATE_TMSTMP) 
from wf_items_history a
inner join wf_items c on c.item_key = a.item_key and c.form_number = 'MV1' and c.ASSIGNED_WORKGROUP = 'NONV'
group by c. item_key, a.create_tmstmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is almost right, you should exclude tmstmp column from group by clause.

```
select c.item_key,min(a.CREATE_TMSTMP) 
from wf_items_history a
inner join wf_items c on c.item_key = a.item_key and c.form_number = 'MV1' and c.ASSIGNED_WORKGROUP = 'NONV'
group by c. item_key;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. It worked. I crossed referenced both tables for verification, and output was not the same. Off by 500 lines. However, the current table is very volatile and represents Items that have no history yet. Once I removed those it matched up. Again Thank you.